# .NET Remoting Callback Exception

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I'm attempting to set up a client server/remoting application that uses .NET remoting on the localhost for communication (127.0.0.1). I cannot use WCF for this application and would like any solution to support events. To this end I've implemented two different solutions that claim to support events/callbacks, but which both fail to work. These are:

http://www.mctainsh.com/Articles/Csharp/RemoteCallback.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62813/NET-Remoting-Events-Explained?fid=1563054&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=26#xx0xx

I receive an exception with both solutions at the point the event is raised on the server. This exception is of the form:

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:57631" (Error code 10061).

Everything suggests that this is probably a firewall issue, but I've enable inbound and outbound calls on these ports across the protocols (I'm on a Windows 7 PC). NB it's only the event callback that fails, calls into the server from the client work and return data as expected.

What other options are there other than the firewall? I'm finding it almost impossible to come up with solutions that will provide more information as to the cause of the exception. I've spent a couple of days on this so far with no real progress. Can I find out any more details about why the exception is being raised?

Comment: `127.0.0.1:57631` is a local address. This is not FW protected. There is nothing listening at that port. You can test this yourself with telnet without any .NET code.

Comment: Setting RemotingConfiguration.CustomErrorMode = CustomErrorModes.Off will give you more detailed exception information.  Remoting with callbacks requires a duplex channel, so the client side may not have been configured correctly.

Comment: @Kim Johnson Unfortunately I'm not getting any new information in the exception with that setting set as you have it.

Comment: @usr: So the FW should not be the issue because I'm using localhost. That in one way is good to know. However, I am still confused by your second comment. I thought the whole point of the example code is that it does set up something to listen to the event otherwise how would it work for other people?h

Comment: I have no idea about that sample code. In general it seems like a simpler architecture to implement events by having the client long poll (like HTTP long polling). That way you entirely remove backchannels from the architecture. No need for open ports. Just have clients ask the server "what's the next event and if there is none wait up to 20sec".